# Trouble to destroy a model with Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

## What is happening?

I am trying to destroy one model via `params`. But when I try to destroy, it appears this error at the console.

```
(node:13350) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: results.map is not a function
    at Query.handleSelectQuery (/home/vagnerwentz/Documents/freelance/autoparanaiba-api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query.js:261:24)
    at Query.formatResults (/home/vagnerwentz/Documents/freelance/autoparanaiba-api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:118:19)
    at /home/vagnerwentz/Documents/freelance/autoparanaiba-api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:71:29
    at tryCatcher (/home/vagnerwentz/Documents/freelance/autoparanaiba-api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/vagnerwentz/Documents/freelance/autoparanaiba-api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/home/vagnerwentz/Documents/freelance/autoparanaiba-api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/vagnerwentz/Documents/freelance/autoparanaiba-api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/home/vagnerwentz/Documents/freelance/autoparanaiba-api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:729:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (/home/vagnerwentz/Documents/freelance/autoparanaiba-api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:93:12)
    at _drainQueue (/home/vagnerwentz/Documents/freelance/autoparanaiba-api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (/home/vagnerwentz/Documents/freelance/autoparanaiba-api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/home/vagnerwentz/Documents/freelance/autoparanaiba-api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)
    at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:130:23)
(node:13350) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:13350) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

## The route that call the function

```js
router.delete('/agricultural/announce/:id', passport.authenticate(), (req, res) => {
    AnnouncementAgricultural.destroy(req, res);
})
```

## The function

```
exports.destroy = async (req, res) => {
    if (!await authorize(req, res, true)) {
        return res.status(400).json({ success: false, errors: "unauthorized" })
    }

    await sequelize.query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;', { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT });

    await Annoucement.destroy({
        where: { id: req.params.id }
    }
    ).then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        res.status(200).json({ success: true })
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
        res.status(400).json({ success: false, errors: err.errors })
    });
}
```

Comment: try to change `type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT` to `type: sequelize.QueryTypes.RAW`

Comment: @Anatoly thanks brother, 
If I'm deleting an ad, wouldn't I have to delete the vehicle's ad?

Comment: If vehicle's ad is a dependent record then yes until you'll set ON DELETE CASCADE for foreign key

Answer (score 0):

The [QueryType](https://sequelize.org/master/variable/index.html#static-variable-QueryTypes) you send tells Sequelize how to format the results. If you are performing `SET` and send `QueryType.SELECT` you will get an error because it tries to use `.map()` on an object:

```js
const results = await sequelize.query("SET NAMES utf8mb4;", {
    type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT }
);
// -> TypeError: results.map is not a function
```

Sadly, in many places the docs confuse [Raw Query](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/raw-queries.html) (sending SQL in plain text) and using `QueryTypes.RAW` (which only should be used to format the results of queries that are not SELECT, UPDATE, etc.). Thus, one could assume that if you are making a Raw Query you should use the same [QueryType](https://sequelize.org/master/variable/index.html#static-variable-QueryTypes) to make the query "raw". At the very least, we should be able to assume it only affects *how* data is returned. The Sequelize [documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js%7ESequelize.html#instance-method-query):

> If you are running a type of query where you don't need the metadata,
> for example a SELECT query, you can pass in a query type to make
> sequelize format the results

Confusingly, if you are using a SELECT then none of these examples cause issues:

```
sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM table");
sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM table", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT });
sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM table", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.UPDATE });
sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM table", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.RAW });
```

But if you use RAW on an UPDATE Sequelize tries to map an object

```js
sequelize.query("UPDATE table SET createdAt = NOW();", {
    type: sequelize.QueryTypes.RAW }
);
```

```
There was an uncaught error TypeError: results.map is not a function
    at Query.handleSelectQuery ([...]/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query.js:261:24)
    at Query.formatResults ([...]/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:123:19)
    at Query.run ([...]/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:76:17)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
    at async [...]/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:619:16
```

So, because you are using `SET` you could, as @Anatoly says, change from `QueryTypes.SELECT` to `QueryTypes.RAW` to avoid the error. But if you don't need the results then don't pass a QueryType at all.

```
await sequelize.query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');
// -> keep on keepin' on
```